# informal text to Html in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, nodes

i have String Like As below :

```
alert(tempstr);//"&lt;b&gt; Testing &lt;/b&gt;"
```

now I want create a ckeditor node with this string

```
NewElem=CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(tempstr);
```

or

```
NewElem.setHtml(tempstr);
```

Both are Assigning just as a Text.

may be using replace (`&lt;` to < ) and  (`&gt;` to>) is possible.my thought is that is not a proper code. Any Other proper code to Assign as Html string?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods accept HTML, not an encoded HTML. So you should find a way to decode HTML in `tempstr`. The easiest solution is to use replace method:

```
var newElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(
    tempstr.replace( /&lt;/gi, '<' ).replace( /&gt;/gi, '>' )
);
```